# silex framework and .htaccess, obtain error 403 access forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, silex

I decided to prove the silex framework. I placed the index.php file, .htaccess and the library silex.phar in the same directory that I called "prova".

But when in my browser I visit the url "localhost/~username/prova" I obtain the error 403 Access Forbidden.

What's my error?

Below the code that I have used in my app.

The index.php file

```php
 <?php

 require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar';

 $app = new Silex\Application();

 $app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
 });

 $app->run();
```

And .htaccess file

```php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteBase /path/to/app
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the _full_ path of you index.php? On the machine, not via a browser.

Comment: the full path of my index.php is `/Users/username/Sites/prova`

Comment: Check your apache error logs. Usually in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: output of the log file: `Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/username/Sites/prova/`

Comment: In your apache configuration for the localhost VirtualHost add this line: `AllowOverride all`.

Comment: if the file is `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, I see that all the `AllowOverride` are set to `All`.

Comment: Now when visit the url `http://localhost/~username/prova/hello/world` i obtain 404 error. And in my log file the error is: `File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/prova/hello`

Comment: You have to enable mod_rewrite. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it in macos. In debian, you need to symlink `/etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load` under mods-enabled and restart apache.

Comment: in the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` the line `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented, than i think that is enabled.

Comment: If you can access localhost/~username/prova (after adding a `->get("/"` route) but not /hello/world the problem is mod_rewrite.

Comment: Yes work! Now it's clear that the problem is mod_rewrite, but like I said above the module is enabled.

Comment: In my `.htaccess` add the line `RewriteBase /~username/prova/` and now works

Comment: @reb2awrl Please write your solution as an answer, and accept as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is running in /~username/prova, then I suspect you need to set:

```
RewriteBase /~username/prova/
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but removing the slash before index.php worked in my test environment.
That leaves the following code inside the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```